# Alter .zip double-click action to work with .7zip (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, zip, archiving, 7-zip

Currently my setup has it so that all file extensions that are supported by 7zip are extracted on double click into a folder pertaining to the name of the archive. This works perfectly on all file extensions except for the main archive extension **[.zip]**. I did not have this issue on my previous version of windows.

How I have it setup is I rigged a registry file to follow the basic format of

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.<file-extention>]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.<file-extention>\Shell]
@="extract"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.<file-extention>\Shell\extract]
@="Extract to Folder"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.<file-extention>\Shell\extract\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\7zG.exe x \"%1\" -o*"
```

I should also mention I currently have disabled base Windows 10 zip functionality so it has no action on double click but I still cannot get the above edits to work with zip. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these 3 lines at the **beginning** of your REG file and it should work.

```
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.zip]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts\.zip]
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not help my issue. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Works fine here. The registry has to be applied for each user separately, to clear the overriding entries. If that doesn't do it, may be you can generate a .zip association report (using FileTypeDiag or FileExtInfo tools) and post them online giving us a link. Would be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: I did use one of the programs you stated above to generate a .txt I couldn't figure out how to use the information it generated but here is a link [ http://pastebin.com/Mp25i8N4 ]. I will however say that I found an interesting thing that Windows actively re-creates the upper key of the two you gave me consistently.

Comment: I've edited my answer ... included a line in the REG file. From the log i see that the .zip file types are still associated with "CompressedFolder". The above REG file removes that.

If that doesn't work, I'll post another approach that will surely work.

Comment: Note that the lines need to be added at the beginning of your REG file, not at the end.

Comment: It worked this time, you put way to much effort into helping me and I thank you for it. :)

Comment: Glad to help, Derprism. And a more accurate way to assign file type association is to define a ProgID for the file type, and set the verbs (like "extract all" there.